# How can I take the body element ($body) from a call to a back-end service in Integration Studio 8.0.0 WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I need help for the following example that I am trying to practice, an example that I have created in the Integration Studio 8.0.0 attachment capture and the code XML file, in the Runtime of the Integration Studio works correctly tests performed with PostMan , but when uploading the project to the API Publisher Portal of the API Manager 3.1.0 the project stops working when I test from the WSO2 DEVELOPER PORTAL, it does not like the expression I have put in the integration studio **json-eval($)** to collect the **body element of each call** when uploading to the API Manager does not work.
I have based myself on the following examples: http://www.xicojunior.com/blog/2020/02/16/iterate/aggregate-fault-handling-in-wso2-ei/
https://medium.com/think-integration/wso2-esb-iterate-and-aggregate-json-requests-ab5fc3617f
By expressing ( one that is valid for the API Manager) I can take the body element of the calls to work with the backend answers and make a valid iteration, test it correctly from WSO2 DEVELOPER PORTAL? Thank you!

- The following XML has been executed in Integration Studio 8.0 and has worked correctly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIRKK.jpg)

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><api context="/api/pets" name="ApiCalls" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><resource methods="GET" uri-template="/findStatus/{tags}"> <inSequence><log description="LOG MESSAGE" level="custom"><property name="LOG MESSAGE" value="INICO LLAMADA"/></log><call description="iTERAMOS SOBRE FIND BY STATUS"><endpoint><http method="get" uri-template="https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/pet/findByTags?tags={uri.var.tags}"><suspendOnFailure><initialDuration>-1</initialDuration><progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor><maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration></suspendOnFailure><markForSuspension><retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension></markForSuspension></http></endpoint></call><log description="LOG MESSAGE" level="custom"><property expression="$ctx:uri.var.tags" name="El Tag introducido es:"/></log><iterate description="iterador" expression="json-eval($)" id="it1"><target><sequence><log description="LOG MESSAGE" level="custom"><property name="LOG MESSAGE" value="Dentro de la iteración"/></log><property description="status" expression="json-eval($.status)" name="uri.var.status" scope="default" type="STRING"/><call><endpoint><http method="get" uri-template="https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/pet/findByStatus?status={uri.var.status}"><suspendOnFailure><initialDuration>-1</initialDuration><progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor><maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration></suspendOnFailure><markForSuspension><retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension></markForSuspension></http></endpoint></call></sequence></target></iterate><log description="LOG MESSAGE" level="custom"><property name="LOG MESSAGE" value="SALIDA ITERACIÓN"/></log><property description="RESPUESTA" name="respuesta" scope="default"><value xmlns=""/></property><aggregate id="it1"><completeCondition><messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/></completeCondition><onComplete aggregateElementType="root" expression="json-eval($)"><log description="" level="custom" separator=";"><property expression="json-eval($)" name="jsonObject"/></log><property description="respuestaFinal" expression="json-eval($)" name="respuestaFinal" scope="default" type="STRING"/><log description="LOG MESSAGE" level="custom"><property expression="$ctx:respuestaFinal" name="LOG MESSAGE"/></log><payloadFactory description="Final" media-type="json"><format>$1</format><args><arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:respuestaFinal"/></args></payloadFactory></onComplete></aggregate><respond description="SEND OUT"/></inSequence><outSequence/><faultSequence/></resource></api>`

- It is expected that when importing(has been performed begging commands with the Controller API 3.1.15) the API created in Integration Studio 8.0.0 to the API PUBLISHER POrtal of API Manager 3.1.0 is done correctly and when testing this API from the WSO2 Developer POrtal works as it worked in the Integration Studio. Could someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: There are two different products, WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Micro Integrator. The integration studio is mainly to develop Integrations for the Micro Integrator. If you want to create APIs in APIM use the Publisher portal.  Can you elaborate on your requirement?